# how to access an widget attached to a treeitem in GWT

Tags: gwt

I'm using GWT TreeItem Widget in my program. I add the checkboxes in to the treeitems dynamically. The code is given below. Please note these items starting with "ti" are TreeItems which were defined earlier in this code..

```
private void polulateTree(List<String> single, List<String> multi, 
        List<String> sub, List<String> local) {

    for (String fm:single) {
        this.tilftSingleV.addItem(new CheckBox(fm));
    }
    for (String vm:multi) {
        this.tilftMultiV.addItem(new CheckBox(vm));
    }
    for (String sm:sub) {
        this.tilftSubV.addItem(new CheckBox(sm));
    }
    for (String lr:local) {
        this.tilftLocalR.addItem(new CheckBox(lr));
    }

}
```

Now I want to access these checkboxes. I don't find a method within TreeItem widget which returns the Widget attached to a certain index. I'm looking for something like below, which I don't find.

```
CheckBox chksingle = (CheckBox)tilftSingleV.getWidget(int index)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the gwt documentation: 
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TreeItem.html

getChild(int index): Gets the child at the specified index.

getWidget(): Gets the Widget associated with this tree item.

```
Widget w = tilftSingleV.getChild(index).getWidget();
if(w instanceof CheckBox)
    //Do something with the CheckBox
```